# Replace missing values of categorical variables and mutiple variables in R

Tags: r, replace, na

I am facing the following issues:

1. I want to replace all NA's of a certain categorical variable with "Unknown", however it does not work.

Here's the code:

> x <- "Unknown"
>
> kd$form_of_address[which(is.na(kd$form_of_address))]) <- x

The problem arises when I perform

> levels(kd$form_of_address)
>   Sadly, my output does not include "Unknown".

2. My data includes ebooks whose weight is always 0. Which code is appropriate to replace NAs of the variable *weight* that have values of the variable *ebook_count* with ebook_count > 0 with 0 ?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Can you provide some simple data as a minimal reproducible example? This will help people more readily help you.

Comment: Check if you have a `character` variable or `factor`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your variable is in factor form, which does not let you change its cell if it is not in the level.

Using `iris`, let's see what may have happened and how it can solved.

```
str(iris)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

We can see `Species` variable is a factor.
We can put some NAs into it by:

```
iris[c(11:13),5] = NA
iris[c(11:15), ]

 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
11          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2    <NA>
12          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2    <NA>
13          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1    <NA>
14          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
15          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa
```

Now, if I try to fill those NAs with "Unknown" using your code:

```
x = "Unknown"
iris$Species[which(is.na(iris$Species))] = x
```

which will generate:

> Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, which(is.na(iris$Species)),
>   value = c(1L,  :   invalid factor level, NA generated

What you can do first is to add a new level to your variable, and **then** you can do so

```
levels(iris$Species) = c(levels(iris$Species), "Unknown")
levels(iris$Species)
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"  "Unknown"   
#You can see now Unknown is one of the levels

iris$Species[which(is.na(iris$Species))] = "Unknown"
table(iris$Species)
    setosa versicolor  virginica    Unknown 
        47         50         50          3
```

Comment: alright :) that worked well :) I have another issues. I tried to replace the remaining NAs with median values. Thus, I did: `medianbook <- median(kd[kd$book_count >0 , 23], na.rm = TRUE)
kd$weight[which(is.na(kd$weight[which(kd$book_count >0)]))]  = medianbook` but it did not work -.-. Any idea ?

Comment: @LiliMatic I get the gist of your question, but can you please provide a producible data set? You can do ``dput(kd)``, which will create a script to generate kd, and you just have to copy and paste it.

Comment: Also, forgive me for the second part. It is a wrong script. It will change **EVERY** value of weight that has corresponding ebook_count > 0, even if weight is NOT NA. I'm going to delete the second part for now.